# Configure Logger Programmatically

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I want to configure my `java.util.logging.Logger` programmatically. According to the [Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19340-01/820-6767/gcbkk/index.html), it seems possible.

However this example shows something is wrong here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.acme.project");
    logger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    logger = null;

    System.gc();

    logger = Logger.getLogger("org.acme.project");
    logger.warning("You shouldn't see this warning!");
    logger.severe("But this error!");
}
```

If you run the code, you'll see both messages. However if you remove `logger = null;` or `System.gc();` you'll only see the correct second one, which proves the garbage collector just removes the configured logger leaving `Logger.getLogger(String)` with creating a new (default) one.

To "solve" this, I could just hold a reference to that particular logger somewhere, but I don't think that's a good idea.

So how do I define a logger programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To "solve" this, I could just hold a reference to that particular logger somewhere, but I don't think that's a good idea.

In releases prior to [JDK6u18](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6274920) the LogManager held strong reference to the logger. After that patch, the [java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger-java.lang.String-) method points the reader towards holding a strong reference:

> Note: The LogManager may only retain a weak reference to the newly created Logger. It is important to understand that a previously created Logger with the given name may be garbage collected at any time if there is no strong reference to the Logger. In particular, this means that two back-to-back calls like getLogger("MyLogger").log(...) may use different Logger objects named "MyLogger" if there is no strong reference to the Logger named "MyLogger" elsewhere in the program.

A common idiom is to use:

```
private static final String CLASS_NAME = Foo.class.getName();
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CLASS_NAME);
```

The reason you define the `CLASS_NAME` too is that you'll use it for the log tracing methods or the `logp` methods

Also, tools like FindBugs will detect this lost logger pattern as:

> LG: Potential lost logger changes due to weak reference in OpenJDK (LG_LOST_LOGGER_DUE_TO_WEAK_REFERENCE)

Comment: Took me a second to realize why I never ran into OP's issue. This is definitely the idiom you should be using.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc for Logger#getLogger references your problem:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger%28java.lang.String%29

> Note: The LogManager may only retain a weak reference to the newly created Logger. It is important to understand that a previously created Logger with the given name may be garbage collected at any time if there is no strong reference to the Logger. In particular, this means that two back-to-back calls like getLogger("MyLogger").log(...) may use different Logger objects named "MyLogger" if there is no strong reference to the Logger named "MyLogger" elsewhere in the program.

In turn Logger#getLogger calls LogManager#addLogger and its documentation also encourages you to hold a reference:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#addLogger%28java.util.logging.Logger%29

> The application should retain its own reference to the Logger object to avoid it being garbage collected. The LogManager may only retain a weak reference.